# androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText error

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-edittext

**Full Error:-**

> ```
> > androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText{39b5cb6VFED..CL. .F....... 188,641-977,812 #7f080097 app:id/edittext aid=1073741824}
> ```

**This image will show you that error...**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpVnh.png

**Detail:-**
i got this error when i was passing data from one activity to another in android.

**Activity 1st Code:-**

```
EditText e1;
e1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittxt);

public void jumpbutton(View view) {
Intent i1 = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
i1.putExtra("user",e1.toString());
startActivity(i1);
}
```

**Activity 2nd Code:-**

```
TextView txt1;
txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtvw);
Bundle bd1 = getIntent().getExtras();
String st1 = bd1.getString("user");
txt1.setText(st1);
```

Answer (score 2):

i successfully solve this error, by adding this

> .getText()

into the first activity code.

**Like this:-**

```
        public void jumpto3(View view) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
            i1.putExtra("user",e1.getText().toString());
            startActivity(i1);
        }
```

Then my error is solved.

***After code is edit:-***
[you can see the result in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1roLX.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the first Activity

```html
    public void openActivity2(){
        EditText editEmail =findViewById(R.id.textEmail) ;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        bundle.putString("emailvalue", editEmail.getText().toString());
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

Then in your second Activity u can get the value of EditText like that

```html
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = getIntent();
                String text = i.getStringExtra("emailvalue" );
                System.out.println(text);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing .getText().toString()  somewhere. find that out and fix it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32204766)